# Why is EF code first migrations asking to create new migration, when already exists?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

So i loaded up an old project to fix a bug.

The project tries to run the initialiser, but upon doing so complains that there are pending database changes, or the model is incorrect etc.

Add-Migration in the console, and it scaffolds the migration. However the newly scaffolded migration is exactly the same as the pre-existing "Intial_Create" migration (this is the 1 and only migration).

So my questions are:

1) Why is it requesting another migration to be addded to run succesffuly, when the site has gone live and already works fine?

2) Why is it scaffolding a migration that already exists?

Comment: Are you sure that the existing migration was applied to the database and that the `__MigrationHistory` table was not corrupted in any way since initial creation? You could try `Update-Database -Script` in order to see if it would change anything in database based on the existing migration without actually changing the database.

Comment: Yeah i've checked the migration history table on the live site and all is there, but i'm running the system locally, as in 1st installation / 1st initialise, so should pick up the initial_create migration file and run that.

Comment: What initializer are you using? DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges, MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, etc? Generate the script as grek40 suggests and check the code that looks for existing __MigrationHistory records. Sometimes the ContextKey can change. If you only had one migration and it is deployed, it's pretty easy to just start over.

Comment: I have the same problem.